# Deploy Prestashop 1.7 on the server

Tags: deployment, prestashop-1.7

The official Prestashop documentation provides instructions for installing Prestashop 1.7 on a server. However, for the deployment process, I'm curious if there's a specific procedure for deploying Prestashop 1.7 from the version control repository that we've been working on locally. This would involve deploying it multiple times. I'm wondering if the deployment process is similar to the installation process, where each deployment would overwrite the previous one. When I perform installations, I notice that there's always a new setup. I'm interested to know if the same applies to deployment. If we need to deploy multiple times on the same server, would we need to go through the setup process each time, or can we simply use the latest code from the version control repository without going through the initial setup again?